# Find the root directory without full path in C#

Tags: c#

Is their any way to find root directory without knowing the full path.

For example, I'm having `Folder\subfolder` I want to find the root directory like `c:\, d:\, e:\`
in which that `subfolder` presents

I had tried by using `DirectoryInfo("path").Root.Name`, `Path.GetPathRoot(path)` but it doesn't works.

Comment: the root of `Folder\subfolder` is `Folder`, how can it possibly know what drive it's on

Comment: What is the context of your folders? Application?

Comment: "it doesn't work" how? What was the input, what were the expected results, and what were the actual results?

Answer (score 5):

You first need to the [full path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) and then the [root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectoryroot.aspx) of  it:

```
 string path = ...
 string root = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(Path.GetFullPath(path));
```

Comment: Would that work if the folder was on anything other than `C:\ ` ?

Comment: Yes. It then uses the [current directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx).

Comment: Yep just tested it :) Had my doubts +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
string result = Path.GetPathRoot(Path.GetFullPath("MyPath"));
```

This uses the current working directory (which is the only way that you can convert a relative path to a full path - the relative path is always relative to the current working directory).

Answer (score 0):

If the subfolder is under the same root as you application you can use `Directory.GetDirectoryRoot`

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectoryroot.aspx